# Returning elevation for point data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, elevation, united-states

I have a dataset for the Western USA and want to get elevations for the point data added to the point attribute table. What is the best way to batch process this so the whole operation is done at one pass?

Comment: This really depends on what layer(s) contain the elevation information.  Do you have a grid, surface, or contour layer that has elevation data?

Comment: I haven't bothered to find a elevation layer yet, hopefully either easy to download and convert, and work with or more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have a raster file with elevation, if not you can download the SRTM.

You can use the ["Point sampling tool"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pointsamplingtool/) Plugin or the geoalgorithms > raster > "raster -> vector" > "grid value to points"

Comment: Thanks for the help, hopefully SRTM is not to tricky or massive to download and load.